# Считались ли в прошлом веке приветствия типа "Привет!", "Пока!'' вульгаризмами?

Tags: стилистика

Сегодня в Глазарии языка прочитал статью В. Г. Костомарова, профессора, доктора филологических наук, «Русский язык за рубежом», 1967. Он пишет: ***«Никогда не повторяйте услышанных вами от русских фамильярно-жаргонных выражений “привет”, “пока” и подобных».***

> Вопрос: **действительно ли такие выражения считались в то время вульгаризмами? Или это очередной пуризм**?

Comment: А сейчас эти слова могут сказать кто угодно кому угодно? Ученик учителю? Бабушка внучке? (Я уехала из СССР более 20 лет назад.)

Comment: Нет, конечно. Эти слова могут быть сказаны только людям, с кем ты на одном уровне. Т.е. нельзя, например, сказать привет учителю, но можно сказать друзьям-товарищам. Т.е. сказать привет может человек любой возрастной категории, независимо от статуса. Эти приветствия фамильярны до сих пор, но жаргонизмами их уже считать уже нельзя!

Comment: >> **Бабушка внучке?** А как же... И внучка бабушке тоже.

Comment: @Серж Но учитель ученику легко может сказать привет или пока. Так что если уровень "ниже", то зачастую можно. Кроме того во многих фирмах подчиненный боссу так тоже может говорить, если там приветствуется "демократический" стиль общения.

Comment: Вряд ли учитель ученику скажет "привет!"  Если учитель позволяет фамильярность, тем самым он позволяет ученику говорить с ним на том же уровне. Конечно, везде есть исключения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю, как классифицировались тогда эти выражения в словарях. Я задал Ваш вопрос, Серж, человеку, который в начале семидесятых годов прошлого века уже получил высшее образование и работал в научно-исследовательском институте. Он говорит, что слова "привет!" и "пока!" в то время употребляли в общении друг с другом одноклассники, однокурсники и вообще молодые люди; а взрослые люди эти выражения, как правило, не употребляли (а если и употребляли, то действительно в фамильярно-дружеском общении). Получается, что тогда эти слова были из разряда "молодёжный сленг". Они были "не по возрасту" в общении взрослых, серьёзных людей; в общении же тесно знакомых и "молодых душой" взрослых людей эти выражения тоже могли употребляться.

Comment: Спасибо, Матвей. Никогда в голову не пришло бы, что такие приветствия воспринимались когда-то как жаргонизмы.

Comment: Посмотрел в словарях. В словаре Ожегова-Шведовой(1949-1992) дана помета: разг. У Ушакова у слова "привет" значение приветствия отсутствует.

Answer (score 3):

1) Что плохого в слове "привет", дружеские и сердечные приветствия всегда обозначались этим словом, например:

Бибикову дружеский **привет!** Напрасно Вы думаете, что я влюблен: фи! [И. А. Гончаров. ] «**Привет** вам, дорогие гости! [А. Ф. Писемский.  (1869)]

2) Привет изображали  жестом:  Поворотив в улицу де Берри, я увидала Тюфякина в своем саду, на террасе. **Он мне сделал привет ручкой.** [П.П. Вяземский).

3) Слово «привет»  можно было сказать «товарищам»: 
Пришел парторг ЦК с завода имени Макса Гельца: ― **Привет, товарищ** Вишневский! **Привет, товарищ** Чурилин, ― глухо сказал Самарин в ответ на дружеское приветствие **начальника**.  Молотов пожал ему руку. ― **Привет**, поздравляю.

4) Да и простые люди  в 30-х годах обменивались  «приветами»: 
**Привет!** ― Как жив, дружище? 
― А-а Павел Стельмах? **Привет, привет!** ― сказал Яхонт, не поворачивая головы.

**Так что более уместными были бы следующие вопросы:** когда «привет» стал неприличным словом, когда опять возродился в качестве молодежного сленга и что с ним будет дальше.

Comment: Вера, я тоже ничего плохого не вижу. Но, в то время, видимо, почему-то считались такие слова сленгом.

Comment: Да, Серж, я тоже знаю, что был период, когда "привет" употреблялось  только в неформальной обстановке, просто очень интересно проследить всю его историю,почему и как менялась область употребления и стилистика слова, есть в этом какая-то загадка. Я, кстати, никогда не думала, что можно было сказать "привет, товарищ ...".

Comment: Вера, да, интересно. Надо спросить на Глазарий языка.

Comment: О слове "глазарий": *Ну а если захочется поговорить с умным человеком, наберите в поисковике «Глазарий языка». Это приложение к уникальному «Школьному энциклопедическому словарю русского языка», статью о котором вы, возможно, запомнили. Загадочное слово «глазарий», полагаю, «детская» версия серьезного «глоссария» – списка, объясняющего малоизвестные слова.

Когда-то глоссарии прилагались к манускриптам с произведениями греческих или римских авторов. Глоссарии были предшественниками словарей. «Глазарий», вглядываясь в живой современный язык, готовит к общению с необычным словарем...*

Comment: Да, Галина, это приложение у меня в Фейсбуке.Там постоянно печатают все, что связано с русским языком, лингвистикой.

Answer (score 1):

Вот статья.

ЗДРАВСТВУЙ, ТОВАРИЩ!

«В русском языке много разных выражений приветствия, но далеко не все из них можно рекомендовать иностранцу. …Никогда не повторяйте услышанных вами от русских фамильярно-жаргонных выражений “привет”, “пока” и подобных. Не употребляйте и включённое во все учебники “как вы поживаете”? Даже русский, произносящий это, кажется иностранцем!»

«Иногда и к незнакомому человеку обращаются непринуждённо, … шире всего распространены выражения “молодой человек” и “девушка”. В магазине вы можете попросить продавца: “Молодой человек, покажите мне серое пальто”, а у кассы кинотеатра вы улыбнетесь и скажете: “Девушка, дайте мне два билета. Только, пожалуйста, в середине, пятнадцатый ряд”. Конечно, если кассир — пожилая женщина, она подумает, что вы смеётесь над ней, и даст вам самые плохие места. Так что подумайте о возрасте, прежде чем сказать “девушка” или “молодой человек”, и если есть сомнения, то вспомните спасительное “товарищ”!»

В. Г. Костомаров («Русский язык за рубежом», 1967)

Comment: Это ответ от 1967 г..

Comment: А разве кто-то утверждает обратное?

Comment: Статье место в тексте вопроса, а она у вас четвёртым ответом идёт.

Answer (score 1):

Варианты "привет" и "пока" по самой своей форме являются сокращениями от более полных приветствий: (привет... кому? какой? и пр. здесь опущено/пропущено) и именно поэтому у носителей языка он "должен" вызывать определенные мысли об уместности/неуместности подобного выражения в различных ситуациях. Такие процессы шли и идут во многих, если не во всех языках, особенно это показательно в современном американском английском ))). По сути, тот, кто приветствует словом "привет" и прощается словом "пока", сознательно (подсознательно?) ограничивает сферу и уровень общения с другим человеком... простым/непритязательным уровнем... пацанским, в лучшем случае - свойским. "Добрый день" и "До свидания" стали как бы "официальными", хотя и они, в свою очередь являются усекновением старых форм. А совсем простые варианты типа "Добрый день, уважаемый, как Ваше здоровье?" кажутся современному "юзеру" абсолютными архаизмами. Уже приняты варианты "спс" вместо "спасибо" в сообщениях. Смайлики ... вместо слов... маты - ВАЩЕ уникальны: они позволяют не искать слова... и речь вырождается, по сути в лай собаки - ведь по ситуации и эмоциям понятно о чем лаются говорящие (((  И не думайте, что я перегибаю палку...